# Removing all IPA files not in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, windows, ios

I currently have have 692 IPA files on my Windows 7 machine, but only 598 IPA files actually in my Applications section of iTunes

I'm guessing this is a result of me pressing the wrong key when deleting apps, and not removing them from my machine (annoying how 'keep files' is always the default selection)

Is there anyway I can remove all of the files that aren't in applications, without having to manually check each one?

Comment: I've added a `windows` tag to avoid having people propose AppleScript solutions (which may exist but won't help you).

Comment: @nick - please edit this to explain if you need a solution only using iTunes (no OS tools or scriptng) or what OS you use. I can see a viable answer for each case, but don't want to write a book on an answer if this is more narrowly scoped.

Comment: Thanks both, sorry for not mentioning it originally (and thanks patrix for the edit based on my other question) but I am indeed running Windows 7.